# I couldn't open database file BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, texshop

I had a problem inserting a new reference in my paper, so I tried to isolate the problem and I ended up with this weird error.

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2016)
The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux
The style file: plainnat.bst
I couldn't open database file mybiblio2.bib
---line 5 of file test.aux
 : \bibdata{mybiblio2
 :                   }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file test.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "theJackson"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "CCCB"
(There were 2 error messages)
```

My latex file is *test.tex*:

```
\documentclass{article}     % use "amsart" instead of "article" for AMSLaTeX format
\usepackage{geometry}                       % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\geometry{letterpaper}                          % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}           % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{graphicx}               % Use pdf, png, jpg, or epsÂ§ with pdflatex; use eps in DVI mode
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}                               

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=15pt} 

\title{Notes}
\author{Gabriele Brambilla}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Try}
bbaucmn  \cite{theJackson}\newline
cnnjfbkjeb \cite{CCCB}

\bibliography{mybiblio2}

\end{document}
```

my bibtex file *mybiblio2.bib*

```
@BOOK{Jackson,
   author = {{Jackson}, J.~D.},
    title = "{Classical Electrodynamics, 3rd Edition}",
booktitle = {Classical Electrodynamics, 3rd Edition, by John David Jackson, pp.~832.~ISBN 0-471-30932-X.~Wiley-VCH , July 1998.},
     year = 1998,
    month = jul,
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1998clel.book.....J},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@BOOK{CCCB,
   author = {{Clarke}, C. and {Carswell}, B.},
    title = "{Principles of Astrophysical Fluid Dynamics}",
booktitle = {Principles of Astrophysical Fluid Dynamics, by Cathie Clarke , Bob Carswell, Cambridge, UK: Cambridge University Press, 2007},
     year = 2007,
    month = mar,
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2007pafd.book.....C},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

Do you have any idea where is the problem? The original file was working fine until few days ago! I am using TexShop.

Comment: There are various possible reasons: you moved the bib-file, you renamed the bib-file (e.g. added an additional extension), you moved the aux-file (by using --output-directory or a similar option).

Comment: Sorry, no one of these three... Does this example work fine for you?

Comment: I didn't test. But if the error message is "I couldn't open  mybiblio2.bib" then it is normally not a problem with an example but with file locations or names. Perhaps you added a space to the file name or something like this.

Comment: I restarted my laptop and now the error is changed and it is similar at the one I was getting before... I will ask a new question.